# Fetching the data from Database laravel using Ajax call

Tags: ajax, laravel

Trying to 'get' the value from local database and trying to print it on console.

Controller method

```
public function getUpdate(Request $request)
{
     if($request->ajax()){
     $customer = Customers::find($request->id);
     return Response($customer);
    }
}
```

Customer.blade.php Ajax Script.

```
 $('tbody').delegate('.btn-edit','click',function(){
     console.log('Monitoring');
     var value = $(this).data('id');
     console.log(value);
     var url='{{URL::to('getUpdate')}}';
     console.log(url);
     $.ajax({
        type : 'get',
        url  : url,
        data : 'success',
        sucess:function(data){
          console.log(data);
        },
        error:function(data){
          console.log('Failed');
          console.log(data);
        }
     });
   });
```

Trying to get the data through ID.

Database fields. 
Id , first_name, last_name and so and so.

Route page code

```
Route::get('/getUpdate','CustomerController@getUpdate');
```

Getting nothing on the console. 
Tried fetching it from postman

```
localhost/public/getUpdate?id:1
```

But could not able to get anything on this.

Comment: You wrote "sucess: function..." instead of "success: function..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have saveral mistake

- you did no send id
- spelling mistake in success function

this is your solution

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'get',
    url  : url,
    data : {'id':your data},
    success: function(res){
      console.log(res);
    },
    error: function(res){
      console.log('Failed');
      console.log(res);
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You have solved my issue. I can able to get it now.

Answer (score 0):

you should return value as array or use this
try in laravel 5.6

```
return response()->json([
    'name' => 'Abigail',
    'state' => 'CA'
]);
```

or on your code

```
public function getUpdate(Request $request)
{
     if($request->ajax()){
     $customer = Customers::find($request->id);
     return Response()->json($customer);
    }
}
```

take a look at this document for more info

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses

Comment: Thanks for the valuable reply and the document attached :)